# Display data with Jade: MongoDB + Monk + ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, pug, monk

I'm trying to show some data from my MongoDB database on the client side, but I keep getting the following error: `8| li 9| #{victim.first-name} > 10| Cannot read property 'first' of undefined`

I've been following this [tutorial](http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2013/node-express-mongo/), but for some reason, I keep running into that error message... any ideas?

Relevant pieces of my app.js file:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('ds012345.mlab.com:12345/dbname');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// Make db accessible to router
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    req.db = db;
    next();
});

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
```

My index.js file:

```
/* GET datatesting page */
router.get('/datatesting', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('data');
    collection.find({},{},function(e,docs){
        res.render('datatesting', {
            "datatesting" : docs
        });
    });
});
```

My datatesting.jade file:

```
extends layout

block content
  h1.
      List of Victims
      ul
          each victim, i in datatesting
              li
                  #{victim.first-name}
```

*Edit: Here's some sample data retrieved from the Mongo shell. There are only 13 documents in the collection.*

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "56e5f15f0e1fc43fe589f5a9"
    },
    "first-name": "Tanisha",
    "last-name": "Anderson",
    "age": 37,
    "gender": "F",
    "killed": "Y",
    "image": "http://google.com",
    "street-address": "Ansel Road, Cleveland, Ohio",
    "city": "Cleveland",
    "state": "Ohio",
    "latitude": 41.52067,
    "longitude": -81.6222,
    "date": "11/1/2014"
}
```

Comment: Try to remove the second empty object parameter in the `find()` method so that it becomes `find({}, function(e,docs){...})`

Comment: Just removed the second `{},` from the `find()` method. Same error. :(

Comment: Have you tested in mongo shell the query `db.data.find()`? If so and that returns some documents, could you edit your question to include the sample documents returned from that `find()` query?

Comment: Making the query in the mongo shell works well and I get all of the documents in my collection. I just added a sample document.

Comment: Use the bracket notation to access the documents property in your jade template, i.e. instead of `#{victim.first-name}` try `#{victim["first-name"]}`

Comment: Tried it. Now it's displaying the error `Cannot read property 'first-name' of undefined`. An improvement though because now it's trying to access "first-name." Not sure why it can't find `victim` though

Comment: Is the name of your database on mlab.com actually "dbname"? Because that might be the issue if you followed my tutorial and did the "use nodetest1" step. To clarify: you might want to change: `var db = monk('ds012345.mlab.com:12345/dbname');` to `var db = monk('ds012345.mlab.com:12345/nodetest1');`

Comment: "dbname" is serving as a placeholder for the actual name of my database. Basically in the real code, "dbname" is replaced by the actual name. Just didn't want to post the actual database name up here.

Comment: @sleepy_daze - ok. Next question: have you tried all of this code locally and does it work there?

Comment: Yep, I'm trying this in a local environment. Haven't deployed anything yet. Running a localhost server for everything but the MongoDB, which is being hosted at mlab.

Comment: @sleepy_daze - ok, but I'd suggest trying a local MongoDB server as well, to make sure the app is functional. If so, we can then narrow it down to an issue with how you're connecting to mongolab and work from there. If it's not functional with a local server, then it must be some other problem with your code.

Comment: @ChristopherBuecheler, I figured it out! Dumb error, but nonetheless, it's fixed. Thanks for all your help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out! Turns out that I needed to double-check my indents in my `.jade` file.

After copying and re-pasting the example from the aforementioned tutorial, I got this:

```
extends layout

block content
    h1.
        Victims
    ul
        each user, i in datatesting
            li
              img(src= "#{user.image}")
```

As you can see, the `h1` tag is not supposed to be aligned with the `ul` tag. After that, it was able to print out my data correctly.